# How to play animation using parameters in a function Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to play an animation based off of a parameter in my function, but the parameter is only recognized as a String. How would I be able to make a function that can run an animation off of a parameter?

Class1:

```
public void FrontDoor(PlayMode openA)
{
    if(!doorLocked)
    {
        if (!doorOpen)
        {
            TestRaycast.hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().Play(openA);
            Invoke("DoorOpen", 1);
        }
        if (doorOpen)
        {
            TestRaycast.hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("CloseDoor1");
            Invoke("DoorClosed", 1);
        }
    }

    //unlocks door
    if(doorLocked)
    {
        if(Display.lockpickActive)
        {
            doorLocked = false;
            Display.lockpickAmount--;
        }
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
switch(hit.collider.tag)
{
     case "front door":
            hit.collider.GetComponent<OpenCloseObjects>().FrontDoor("OpenDoor1");
            break;
}
```